# Tangent unit vectors?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

The question asks to find the unit tangent vector at the specified value of the parameter. I think I know the process, but I can't for the life of me figure out why I am getting the wrong answer.

$r(t)=4t$ **i** $- \ln t$ **j**, where $t=e$

$r'(t)=4$ **i** $- \dfrac1t$ **j**

$r'(e)=4$ **i** $- \dfrac1e$ **j**

$||r'(e)|| = \dfrac{\sqrt{16e^2+1}}{e}$

$\dfrac{r'(e)}{||r'(e)||} = \dfrac{4e}{\sqrt{16e^2+1}}$**i** $- \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{16e^2+1}}$**j**

Comment: What is the answer you expect?

Comment: @AustinMohr I don't know, but the online website which I have to upload the answer to says I'm wrong. I have tried uploading different formats too and it still didn't work

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks correct to me. Probably if you show your professor your solution, you will be awarded credit. If the website has a menu of common mathematical symbols, you might try using the "e" from there rather than typing it on your keyboard.